# JOIN SQL query with two tables

Tags: join

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.surname, p.id as p_id, SUM(t.summa)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN pupils p ON p.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN tulovlar t ON t.pupilid = p.id
WHERE u.turi = 3
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.surname
```

sql response is showing this error

```
#1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'crm_test.p.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: you need to include these fields as part of the group by

 u.id, u.name, u.surname, p.id as p_id, SUM(t.summa)

or remove other fields from your select and just return u.id

Hope that helps.

Comment: don't understood. give some more comment, please ...

Comment: try this:

SELECT u.id, u.name, u.surname, p.id as p_id, SUM(t.summa)
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN pupils p ON p.userid = u.id
LEFT JOIN tulovlar t ON t.pupilid = p.id
WHERE u.turi = 3
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, u.surname, p.id as p_id, SUM(t.summa)
ORDER BY u.surname

Comment: worked (I corrected it a little). thanks...